# images in various locations in included Asciidoc files

Tags: image, markup, asciidoc

I have an `AsciiDoc` structure like this:

- Documentation.adoc

  - DeveloperDocumentation/DeveloperDocumentation.adoc
  - DeveloperDocumentation/DeveloperDocumentationPart1.adoc
  - UserDocumentation/UserDocumentation.adoc

And this content:

in `Documentation.adoc`:

```
include::DeveloperDocumentation/DeveloperDocumentation.adoc
include::UserDocumentation/UserDocumentation.adoc
```

in `DeveloperDocumentation/DeveloperDocumentation.adoc`:

```
include::DeveloperDocumentationPart1.adoc
```

in `DeveloperDocumentation/DeveloperDocumentationPart1.adoc` (also in 'DeveloperDocumentation' directory):

```
image::devScreenshot.png[]
```

My problem: the image is displayed in the rendered DeveloperDocumentationPart1.adoc and DeveloperDocumentation.adoc, but not in the Documentation.adoc.

I am aware that the Documentation.doc cannot find the image as the image path is not correct in relation to the Documentation.doc.
So I tried to solve it with the `:imagesdir:` attribute but I cannot get it to work. And I cannot set one fixed image directory path, anyways, because not all images will be in one directory.

I read the docs but I could not find a working solution for `imagesdir`:

[AsciiDoc: Set the Images Directory](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/macros/images-directory/#imagesdir-attribute-syntax)
[AsciiDoc: Image Paths and Formats](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/pdf-converter/latest/image-paths-and-formats/#imagesdir)

Help would be appreciated :-)

Comment: It seems not possible and not indented: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/issues/826#issuecomment-1128688992

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve by changing the `imagesdir` attribute before the respective include:

in `Documentation.adoc`:

```
:imagesdir: DeveloperDocumentation

include::DeveloperDocumentation/DeveloperDocumentation.adoc

:imagesdir: UserDocumentation

include::UserDocumentation/UserDocumentation.adoc
```

The docs don't mention this anywhere, but it works...